# Setting the value of a pipeline variable from a Groovy script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins on Windows, declarative pipeline.  Assuming the follwing Groovy script inside a script() block in my pipeline:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def request = httpRequest "https://localhost/job/MyBuild/lastBuild/api/json"
def requestJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(request.getContent())
// How do I set the value of a pipeline variable to this: requestJson['result']
```

Comment: What's your pipeline value?  ( groovy variable, shell variable, job parameter, environment variable)

Comment: The pipeline variable is an environment variable.

Comment: you can't overwrite an exist environment variable, but assign to an new one by `env.new_variable_name=requestJson['result']`